Is there a way to get file data from associated file?
Let's say I want to associate my app with '.val' file. So that when user clicks on '.val' file anywhere on their phone, the app opens and I receive data from the file without using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
Is there a way to get such data from the intent? Thank you for the help in advance!
Here is the way I am currently getting the file path from the opened file's intent if that would be helpful
    Uri uri = intent.getData();

            if(uri!=null) {
                String filePath = getFilePathFromUri(this, uri);
                Log.d(TAG, "Received file path from intent: " + filePath);
               // logic with the path
            }


    private  String getFilePathFromUri(Context context, Uri uri) {
        String filePath = null;

        if ("content".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
            filePath = getDataColumn(context, uri);
        } else if ("file".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
            filePath = uri.getPath();
        }

        return filePath;
    }


Pass the Uri to openInputStream() on a ContentResolver. Please delete getFilePathFromUri().

@CommonsWare it worked, thank you!
